# Packaging for PPA .deb Creation Missing Files

Tags: ppa, packaging

So after floundering around from doc to doc I've latched onto and been following this tutorial: http://packaging.ubuntu.com/html/packaging-new-software.html

So I tried the steps in there and started running into troubles. Googling around has been largely unhelpful. I have a very standard autotools c++ project which builds a library and some executables. I wanted to make a libfoo-dev style package out of it and stick it up on a PPA.

To help show what I'm doing, I've stuck a script that does the steps proposed in the tutorial (so far as I am understanding them correctly..). Here's what I have: https://github.com/kevinkreiser/ppa-libprime-server

I have a bash script in there `build.sh` which has all the steps I've been doing. At first I was having trouble getting `dh_*` to build anything from my project until @sneetsher clued me into changing the rule file to do autoreconf. At this point my only issues are `W: libprime-server0: empty-binary-package` and `W: prime-server-bin: empty-binary-package`.

And like it says, the problem is now that a couple of my packages don't have much of anything in them:

```
user@pc$ lesspipe libprime-server0_0.3.2-0ubuntu1_amd64.deb 
libprime-server0_0.3.2-0ubuntu1_amd64.deb:
 neues Debian-Paket, Version 2.0.
 Größe 2004 Byte: control-Archiv= 528 Byte.
     425 Byte,    12 Zeilen      control              
     160 Byte,     2 Zeilen      md5sums              
 Package: libprime-server0
 Source: libprime-server
 Version: 0.3.2-0ubuntu1
 Architecture: amd64
 Maintainer: Kevin Kreiser <kevinkreiser@gmail.com>
 Installed-Size: 26
 Section: contrib/libs
 Priority: optional
 Homepage: https://github.com/kevinkreiser/prime_server
 Description: Service oriented distributed computing API
  A set of APIs designed around the zeromq butterfly pattern
  specifically focused on servicing http requests

*** Contents:
drwxr-xr-x root/root         0 2016-04-21 11:48 ./
drwxr-xr-x root/root         0 2016-04-21 11:48 ./usr/
drwxr-xr-x root/root         0 2016-04-21 11:48 ./usr/share/
drwxr-xr-x root/root         0 2016-04-21 11:48 ./usr/share/doc/
drwxr-xr-x root/root         0 2016-04-21 11:48 ./usr/share/doc/libprime-server0/
-rw-r--r-- root/root       167 2016-04-18 11:04 ./usr/share/doc/libprime-server0/changelog.Debian.gz
-rw-r--r-- root/root      1558 2016-04-15 09:46 ./usr/share/doc/libprime-server0/copyright

user@pc:~/sandbox/ppa-libprime-server/build$ lesspipe prime-server-bin_0.3.2-0ubuntu1_amd64.deb 
prime-server-bin_0.3.2-0ubuntu1_amd64.deb:
 neues Debian-Paket, Version 2.0.
 Größe 1994 Byte: control-Archiv= 517 Byte.
     437 Byte,    12 Zeilen      control              
     160 Byte,     2 Zeilen      md5sums              
 Package: prime-server-bin
 Source: libprime-server
 Version: 0.3.2-0ubuntu1
 Architecture: amd64
 Maintainer: Kevin Kreiser <kevinkreiser@gmail.com>
 Installed-Size: 26
 Depends: libprime-server0 (= 0.3.2-0ubuntu1)
 Section: contrib/misc
 Priority: optional
 Homepage: https://github.com/kevinkreiser/prime_server
 Description: Service oriented distributed computing executables
  A set of executables for use in running a distributed http service

*** Contents:
drwxr-xr-x root/root         0 2016-04-21 11:48 ./
drwxr-xr-x root/root         0 2016-04-21 11:48 ./usr/
drwxr-xr-x root/root         0 2016-04-21 11:48 ./usr/share/
drwxr-xr-x root/root         0 2016-04-21 11:48 ./usr/share/doc/
drwxr-xr-x root/root         0 2016-04-21 11:48 ./usr/share/doc/prime-server-bin/
-rw-r--r-- root/root       167 2016-04-18 11:04 ./usr/share/doc/prime-server-bin/changelog.Debian.gz
-rw-r--r-- root/root      1558 2016-04-15 09:46 ./usr/share/doc/prime-server-bin/copyright
```

The first package does work if I re-name the files back to `libprime-server1.install` and `libprime-server1.dirs`. I haven't be able to figure out what I'm doing wrong with the `-bin` package. `bzr` asks about the type of package I am making and I choose `l` for `library` should I be choosing something else?

EDIT:

The whole thing works: https://launchpad.net/~kevinkreiser/+archive/ubuntu/prime-server

With the help of @sneetsher I was able to get all of this up on a ppa and working properly in trusty! I just want to thank @sneetsher for all of the help and patience along the way. Hopefully this script can help others looking to do something similar: https://github.com/kevinkreiser/ppa-libprime-server/blob/master/build.sh

Comment: Is the subject project this one https://github.com/kevinkreiser/prime_server?

Comment: @sneetsher yep thats the one. might there be something wrong with the way i've setup autotools that is breaking the packaging tools?

Comment: so i've gotten around the original issue and updated the question above to reflect that. i'm now at the point where the contents of the packages aren't quite right despite it `configuring`, `building` and `testing` fine

Comment: I tried to build it to see its installation structure, but I got a make error. submitted a report [here](https://github.com/kevinkreiser/prime_server/issues/37).

Comment: This should be fixed now, I would greatly appreciate it if you gave it another go! Thanks again for your help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, I could test it on Ubuntu 14.04 and (with last commit) in Ubuntu 16.04.

- As you are new to packaging, it better to enable the verbose `debhelper` output. Uncomment `export DH_VERBOSE=1` in the `rules` file.
- The package seems to depend on `autoreconf` not just `automake`/`autotools`. So change the `rules` main line to:

  ```
  %:
      #dh $@ --with autotolls-dev
      dh $@ --parallel --list-missing --with autoreconf
  ```

  and add `dh-autoreconf` to build dependencies in `control` file.

  So you are now longer need to pre-generate the auto build files by running `./autogen.sh` manually. Keep in mind that every thing should be done through `rules` file, otherwise it will fail when it is built on PPA server with clean source tree.
- One of the tests fails, I go around by skipping them. overriding the `dh_auto_test`. So I add this to the `rules` file:

  ```
  override_dh_auto_test:
      echo skip auto-test
  ```

  leave it later to be fixed.
- For the empty `libprime-server` package, this is because it's has a wrong name.

  `libprime-server` in `control` file and `libprime-server1` with `1` in others (like `libprime-server1.install`)
- Yes, `lintian` (QA tool) raises that warning because it expect to be the major version of the package. Yes, it should be ok to rename it to `libprime-server0`. There is only one note, you have to clean up the build tree from the previous build. So delete `debian/libprime-server1` folder & try rebuild again.

  You can add as many packages as you want, see updated files below.
- Yes, dependencies should include the binary package, `libprime-server0`. The source package `libprime-server` it is not a dependency on any.
- I wasn't using your script to build, I was using another manual work-flow (Download original zip archive, extract it, add debian folder, build using `debuild`). I couldn't reproduce same issue as that one of empty binary packages.

  I could reproduce it with `build.sh`. The problem, you have changed the full `debian/`:

  ```
  rm -rf libprime-server/debian
  cp -rp ../debian libprime-server
  ```

  but committed only one file

  ```
  bzr add debian/source/format
  ```

  to fix it, commit the whole folder:

  ```
  bzr add debian
  ```

  `bzr builddeb` seems to use only the commit/tag (with `Debian` label) files, not the current working tree.

Here are the files I have changed:

1. **`debian/rules`**

   ```
   #!/usr/bin/make -f
   # -*- makefile -*-

   # Uncomment this to turn on verbose mode.
   export DH_VERBOSE=1

   %:
       #dh $@  --with autotools-dev
       dh $@ --parallel --list-missing --with autoreconf

   override_dh_auto_test:
       echo skip auto-test
   ```
2. **`debian/control`**

   ```
   Source: libprime-server
   Priority: optional
   Maintainer: Kevin Kreiser <kevinkreiser@gmail.com>
   Build-Depends: debhelper (>= 9), autotools-dev, dh-autoreconf, libcurl4-openssl-dev, libzmq3-dev
   Standards-Version: 3.9.5
   Section: libs
   Homepage: https://github.com/kevinkreiser/prime_server
   Vcs-Git: git://github.com/kevinkreiser/prime_server.git

   Package: libprime-server-dev
   Section: contrib/libdevel
   Architecture: any
   Depends: libprime-server0 (= ${binary:Version}), ${misc:Depends}
   Description: Service oriented distributed computing API
    A set of APIs designed around the zeromq butterfly pattern
    specifically focused on servicing http requests

   Package: libprime-server0
   Section: contrib/libs
   Architecture: any
   Depends: ${shlibs:Depends}, ${misc:Depends}
   Description: Service oriented distributed computing API
    A set of APIs designed around the zeromq butterfly pattern
    specifically focused on servicing http requests

   Package: prime-server-bin
   Section: contrib/misc
   Architecture: any
   Depends: libprime-server0 (= ${binary:Version}), ${misc:Depends}
   Description: Service oriented distributed computing API
    A set of APIs designed around the zeromq butterfly pattern
    specifically focused on servicing http requests
   ```
3. `libprime-server1.install` is renamed to **`libprime-server0.install`**
4. `libprime-server1.dir` is renamed to **`libprime-server0.dir`**
5. Create **`prime-server-bin.dirs`**

   ```
   usr/bin
   ```
6. Create **`prime-server-bin.install`**

   ```
   usr/bin/*
   ```
7. **`build.sh`**

   ```
   #!/bin/bash

   set -e

   rm -rf build
   mkdir build
   pushd build

   #get prime_server software
   #sudo apt-get install autoconf automake libtool make gcc-4.9 g++-4.9 lcov
   sudo apt-get install libcurl4-openssl-dev libzmq3-dev
   git clone --branch 0.3.2 --recursive  https://github.com/kevinkreiser/prime_server.git
   tar pczf prime_server.tar.gz prime_server
   rm -rf prime_server

   #start building the package
   sudo apt-get install dh-make dh-autoreconf bzr-builddeb
   bzr dh-make libprime-server 0.3.2 prime_server.tar.gz
   rm -rf libprime-server/debian
   cp -rp ../debian libprime-server
   pushd libprime-server
   bzr add debian
   bzr commit -m "Initial commit of Debian packaging."
   bzr builddeb -- -us -uc
   #TODO: sign the package
   popd

   #TODO: push the package to the ppa

   #TODO: make an ITP for inclusion in mainline

   popd
   ```

Comment: this is great i'll give it a try tomorrow morning as soon as i get a chance!

Comment: what determins the package name? lintian complains that it doesnt match the soname (because its libprime_server.so.0.0.0) and suggests that i name the package libprime-server0 but doing this in the control file and renaming the .dirs and .install files create empty packages again. also i am building some executables, can i add a package to the control file like prime-server-bin and get those to land in there?

Comment: ive pushed up the updates you suggested and they work great to build the library packages!  i was wondering though, when we say in the dev package that it depends on the nondev package, should it refer to the nondev package via its package name. in other words should the depends line in the dev package be `libprime-server1` instead of `libprime-server`: ? if its the package name that its referring to then it seems like it should right?

Comment: @KevinKreiser, updated the answer to cover that too.  I have only one thing that may be an issue as I'm not sure if Launchpad supports Git submodules. Try it and let me know.

Comment: i had tried (before asking) renaming to `libprime-server0.install` and `libprime-server0.dirs`but it didnt seem to work. i still get: `W: libprime-server0: empty-binary-package`. Also I tried before asking to get the `-bin` package working but that doesnt seem to be working for me either, I get: `W: prime-server-bin: unknown-section optional` and `W: prime-server-bin: empty-binary-package`. I've pushed up the changes to https://github.com/kevinkreiser/ppa-libprime-server. I can't quite tell what I'm missing there.

Comment: @KevinKreiser, I copied your last debian folder as it is and works fine, `libprime-server0` is not empty, it contains the `.so` lib. for section, I was wrong, updated answer and here full list of available sections: https://www.debian.org/doc/debian-policy/ch-archive.html#s-subsections

Comment: I'll update my question based on your answer because for some reason I'm still having empty `-bin` and `-server0` packages

Comment: @KevinKreiser, I've updated the answer, problem was with `build.sh` script.

Comment: thank you very much for all your patience with me! ive made the change (makes perfect sense) to the build script and now it seems like everything is working! i'm going to make sure the packages install cleanly (locally) and then i'll mark this answered. thanks again for everything!